# Automatic change of background images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this jquery code:

```
 (function() {
    var curImgId = 0;
    var numberOfImages = 42; // Change this to the number of background images
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(/background' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
        curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
    }, 15 * 1000);
})();
```

and this CSS:

```
.body-1{
    background: url("../background/Living Room.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;


    width: 100%;
    height:100%;

}
```

In my background folder I have 2 images with different names. When I load the page the image which is referred to in CSS code gets loaded, but when another one should load using jquery I keep getting the white background.

Could anyone help me with this matter?

Comment: you are missing `/` after word `background`

Comment: You have space in image file name. dey are n't actually allowed, it will break depending upon browsers/doctype/servers.

Comment: In your css you have `../background/Living Room.jpg` and in jQuery you don't provide two dots before path. These two dots are used to go up on one level of path tree. Try to write like this in `jQuery:url(../background/' + curImgId + '.jpg)`. And as Vivek said you have a space in a CSS path.